# Google Play Console - Reuse Signing Key

Tags: google-play, keystore, android-app-signing

I've created an app draft in the Google Play Console. In the App Releases screen, I was asked to choose whether or not I'd like to enroll my app in Google Play App Signing. I do want to enable this feature, but I am confused as to whether I should press the Continue button or the Reuse Signing Key button.

[image: image link]

I've got 2 apps published in the store already - one of them is enrolled in Google Play App Signing and is signed with a JKS keystore that I will refer to as X, and the other one is not enrolled and uses a different keystore - keystore Y. My new app, the draft, uses keystore X (the one used in the app that has Google Play App Signing enabled).

Since keystore X is already being used in an app which has Google Play App Signing enabled, is Reuse Signing Key or Continue the correct option to choose for the new app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press continue. You only need "re-use signing key" in very limited cases where you need two apps to be signed with the same key to share code execution.